# Threading in unity with C# for optimisation

Tags: c#, multithreading

So here is my code: the idea is that in the input system class we find some data from the user, then listen to this data from the threading class and process it in a new thread, then we return the processed data to the main thread.

It works, but it is slow ... why is this?

I'm new to coding, so hopefully that explains the errors ...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class InputSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
        
    public EventHandler<dataStore> onRequest;

    public class dataStore : EventArgs
    {

        public int[] dataPass;

    }

    public int[] newData;

    void Start()
    {

        int[] test = new int[] { 6, 6, 6 };

        newData = test;

    }
    
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {

            onRequest?.Invoke(this, new dataStore { dataPass = newData });

        }  

    }

}

public class StartThread : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {

        InputSystem  input = GetComponent<InputSystem >();
        input.onRequest += findPath;

    }
        
    requestData pData;
    returnData rData;
    
    public void findPath(object sender, InputSystem.dataStore data)
    {

        pData = data.dataToPass;

        RequestPath(method);

    }
        
    public static void RequestPath(Action doThing)
    {

        ThreadStart thread = delegate
        {

            doThing();

        };

        thread.Invoke();

    }
    
    public Queue<Action> toRun = new Queue<Action>();
        
    public void method()
    {

        PathAlg test = new PathAlg();

        Action toQueue = () =>
        {

            requestData data = pData;

            rData.data = test.method(data);

        };

        lock (toRun)
        {

            toRun.Enqueue(toQueue);

        }

    }

    void Update()
    {

        while (toRun.Count > 0)
        {

            lock (toRun)
            {

                Action runThis = toRun.Dequeue();

                runThis();

                foreach(int n in rData)
        
                   {
    
                       print(n);

                   }

            }


        }
        
    }

}

public struct requestData 
{

    public int[] data;

}

public struct returnData
{
 
    public int[] data;
    
}

public class pathAlg
{
    
    public int[] method(requestData data)
    {

        int[] example = new int[data.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i< example.Length; i++)
            {

                example[i] = i+1;

            }

            return example;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your queue isn't thread-safe, you have a bad race condition there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by using coroutines rather than threads.